# Locale changes every other page load

Tags: php, locale

In one of our web apps the user can select preferred language, so we need to dynamically set locale per user. Basically:

```
function i18n_date($format, $date, $locale) {
    setlocale(LC_TIME, $locale);
    return strftime($format, $date);
}
```

The problem is that every other page load, the locale is changed to the default, between `setlocale()` and `strftime()`. According to [the PHP docs](http://se.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php#refsect1-function.setlocale-notes) this should be expected from "*multithreaded server API like IIS or Apache on Windows*", but our server Apache build is non threaded:

```
Server version: Apache/2.2.17 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Nov  3 2011 02:13:53
Server's Module Magic Number: 20051115:25
Server loaded:  APR 1.4.2, APR-Util 1.3.9
Compiled using: APR 1.4.2, APR-Util 1.3.9
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     Prefork
  threaded:     no
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APACHE_MPM_DIR="server/mpm/prefork"
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=128
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/apache2"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/lib/apache2/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/var/run/apache2.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_LOCKFILE="/var/run/apache2/accept.lock"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="apache2.conf"
```

So then why is this happening?

Answer (score 2):

setlocale() is not persistent, you need to set it everytime you need it.

Comment: Look at my function `i18n_date` in the question

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question a bit. Did you just recently installed the locales? Then a restart of Apache will help. Else I would dump the output of setlocale() as it returns a string, maybe this could help you.

Answer (score 0):

If locales is not persistent, then use something that is PERSISTENT (SESSION rings any bells???).

When the user selects his Locale, save it into the $_SESSION associative array.

Then everytime you load a page, first check whether the variable exists. If it does, then set down the locale else ask for it.

```
if (isset($_SESSION['locale'])){
    setlocale($_SESSION['locale']);
}
else{
    //ask for the locale or whatever you need to do
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, but I don't you think understand the problem. "*The problem is that every other page load, the locale is changed to the default, between setlocale() and strftime().*"